# EF Linq group by ICollection of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

All,

I have a Linq query which fetches a list of events which works great. The problem I'm facing is that *Events* contains a ICollection of *Artists* called **headliners** and in the list I only want 1 event per,set of, Artist(s).

The query underneath works fine but: **I require a top 10 of *Events* but only one *Event* per, set of, artist(s)** for sorting the popularity of the artist with highest popularity can be used - not what i want.

```
 Context.Events
      .Where(x => x.Stage.Venue.AreaId == 1 && x.StartDateTimeUtc > DateTime.UtcNow && x.IsVerified)
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Headliners.Max(y => y.Popularity))
      .Take(10)
      .ToList();
```

How can I adjust the query above that I only get one *Event* per *Artist*. I would need to do some sort of grouping to see if the event is performed by same (set of) Artist(s).

I'm looking into using the Artist's primary key but because it is an collection i cannot get it to work. I already tried the String.Join to get a single unique key for the headliners. This is however not support in entity framework.

Is this something that can (gracefully) be supported by Linq to EF?

The following SQL query does almost what i want expect that it won't work with multiple artist for the same event

```
 SELECT MAX(E.EventId), MAX(E.Name)
 FROM [dbo].[Events] E
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Stages] S ON E.StageId = S.StageId
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Venues] V ON S.VenueId = V.VenueId
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Areas] A ON V.AreaId = A.AreaId
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Headliners] H ON E.EventId = H.EventId
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Artists] A2 ON A2.ArtistId = H.ArtistId
 WHERE E.IsVerified = 1 AND E.StartDateTimeUtc>GETDATE() AND  A.AreaId = 1
 GROUP BY A2.ArtistId, A2.Name, A2.EchoNestHotttnesss
 ORDER BY A2.EchoNestHotttnesss desc
```

Comment: can you provide your model and what exactly you asking for. It will be great if you provide a expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Challenging task, but here it is:

```
var availableEvents = db.MusicEvents.Where(e => 
     e.Stage.Venue.AreaId == 1 && e.StartDateTimeUtc > DateTime.UtcNow && e.IsVerified);

var topEvents =
    (from e1 in availableEvents
     where e1.Headliners.Any() &&
        !availableEvents.Any(e2 => e2.StartDateTimeUtc < e1.StartDateTimeUtc &&
            !e2.Headliners.Any(a2 => !e1.Headliners.Any(a1 => a1.Id == a2.Id)) &&
            !e1.Headliners.Any(a1 => !e2.Headliners.Any(a2 => a2.Id == a1.Id)))
     orderby e1.Headliners.Max(a => a.Popularity) descending
     select e1)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

The first subquery (`availableEvents`) is just for reusing the "availability" filter inside the main query. It does not execute separately.

The critical part is the condition

```
!availableEvents.Any(e2 => e2.StartDateTimeUtc < e1.StartDateTimeUtc &&
    !e2.Headliners.Any(a2 => !e1.Headliners.Any(a1 => a1.Id == a2.Id)) &&
    !e1.Headliners.Any(a1 => !e2.Headliners.Any(a2 => a2.Id == a1.Id)))
```

The idea is to exclude the later events for the same set of headliners. It should be read this way:

*Exclude the event if there is another available event starting earlier and there is no at least one artist from either event that is not headliner of the other event (i.e. they have the same headliner set).*

Comment: Nice solution, but I think he really should consider creating a link from `Artist` to `Event` too in his model. All those `Any` will probably be bad for performance (which may or may not be an issue of course depending on his requirements).

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Actually they are not so bad - all they lead to "link" table PK index seeks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

A pretty decent partial-LINQ lazily executed solution could be done in this way:

Firstly, get your query up to the ordered events based on popularity:

```
var evArtists = Context.Events
  .Where(x => x.Stage.Venue.AreaId == 1 && x.StartDateTimeUtc > DateTime.UtcNow && x.IsVerified)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Headliners.Max(y => y.Popularity));
```

Secondly, since a `ICollection<Artist>` can be unordered yet forming equal set, creates an *intermediate function* to check if two `ICollection<Artist>` are of identical members:

```
private bool areArtistsEqual(ICollection<Artist> arts1, ICollection<Artist> arts2) {
    return arts1.Count == arts2.Count && //have the same amount of artists
        arts1.Select(x => x.ArtistId)
        .Except(arts2.Select(y => y.ArtistId))
        .ToList().Count == 0; //when excepted, returns 0
}
```

Thirdly, use the above method to get the unique artists set in the query results, put the results in a `List`, and fill the `List` with the number of elements you need (say, 10 elements):

```
List<Events> topEvList = new List<Events>();
foreach (var ev in evArtists) {
    if (topEvList.Count == 0 || !topEvList.Any(te => areArtistsEqual(te.Headliners, ev.Headliners)))
        topEvList.Add(ev);
    if (topEvList.Count >= 10) //you have had enough events
        break;
}
```

Your result is in the `topEvList`.

**Benefits:**

The solution above is *lazily executed* and is also pretty decent in the sense that you can really *break down* the logic and *check* your execution piece by piece *without* breaking the performance.

Note that using the method above you do not need to refer to the `evArtists` (which is your large query) other than by its individual element `ev`. Using full-LINQ solution is *possible*, yet you may need to refer to `evArtists.Any` to find the duplicates set of artists (as you do have have memory of what sets has been chosen before) from the original ordered query itself (rather than by simply using its element (`ev`) one by one).

This is possible because you create a temporary memory `topEvList` which records what sets have been chosen before and only need to check if the next element (`ev`) is not among the already selected set of artists. Thus, you do *not* impair your performance by checking you set of artists against the whole ordered query every time.

---

**Original:**

You are almost there actually. What you further need are `LINQ` `GroupBy` and `First`, and put your `Take(10)` the last:

```
var query = Context.Events
  .Where(x => x.Stage.Venue.AreaId == 1 && x.StartDateTimeUtc > DateTime.UtcNow && x.IsVerified)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Headliners.Max(y => y.Popularity))
  .GroupBy(a => a.ArtistId) 
  .Select(e => e.First())
  .Take(10);
```

Since in by this query  you have sorted your headliner artist:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Headliners.Max(y => y.Popularity))
```

Then you only need to group your headliners by `ArtistId`:

```
.GroupBy(a => a.ArtistId)
```

Thus each artist would be having one group. Then next, you only want the first element in the group (supposedly the most popular *Event per Artist*):

```
.Select(e => e.First())
```

And thus you will get all the most popular events per artist. And lastly, among these most popular events per artist, you only want to take 10 of them, thus:

```
.Take(10);
```

And you are done!

---

Comment: It doesn't work because the grouping: '.GroupBy(a => a.ArtistId)' does not seem to be allowed as Headliners is an ICollection of Artist object, and the 'a' is an Event object.

Comment: @Frank in that case, what are the fields you have in your events?

Comment: There is no ArtistId in event, it contains a many-to-many (auto EF) relation called Headliners which contains Artist Objects. The issue is with this relation.

Comment: The Context.Event has an ICollection<Artist> property called Headliners. And the Context.Artist has an ICollection<Event> has a property called Headlining. It is a many-to-many relation which is auto generated by EF. An Event can van 0-1-more Artist headlining and an Artist can headline 0-1-more Events.

Comment: Events should be grouped by all performing artist (e.g. the Event has both artist A & B - If it is only Artist A and not B  - or - A and C- it is considered a different event). If more event are returned only the nearest in time (StartDateTimeUtc) should be returned. The list should be sorted by the hotttness/popularity of the max hotttness/popularity performing.

Comment: @Frank OK, got it! Thanks! Let me work out for while.

Comment: @Frank it seems like it may require additional intermediate functions other than LINQ. But it could be working if we do so. Do you only look for LINQ solution, or you are OK with any working solution?

Comment: I would preferably like a LINQ (EF) solution but I'm opens to others. I can think of many dirty hacks but hope there is a graceful solution.

Comment: a simplified version by which the first (most popular) Artist in the Headliners is used for grouping & sorting would also work for now..

Comment: with First i could work but it still needs the Grouping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105714/discussion-between-ian-and-frank).

Comment: @Frank updated the solution to make it more decent without impairing the performance! ;)